# JBoss 7 project libraries as a module

Tags: maven, jboss, module, jboss7.x, war

My project's war, after adding some maven dependencies, increased in size to 32MB!

I need to reduce that size. Gooogling around I found that using **modules** could be the way.

What's the best practice? Adding each library as a new module? Creating a module with "all libraries" ? I don't even know if that's possible.

So, I have, for example:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I want to add "**provided**" to that dependency, and keep the JAR in JBoss, without including it in my war.

How?

PS: I know that it will be available to all deployed applications. It's good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Separating the application from it's libraries does not sound like a good idea to me - you are dramatically increasing the application's context dependency and will be unable to deploy the application on another server without tinkering with it's internals first. This might not be possible/allowed in a production environment.

A `war` of 32MB...so what? A couple extra MB is not a real problem nowadays. A business application weighing in with a couple of hunderds MB is not so rare.

So, after a stern warning, this is how it could be done:

Go to the `JBOSS_HOME/modules` directory and create a directory hierarchy for the artifact coordinates (an com.example dependency would sit in the /com/example/ folder).

In this folder, create a folder `main`.

Put the library `jar` into the main folder.

Create a `module.xml` file and fill it:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.example">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mylib.jar"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

I am not sure if restarting the server is necessary.

In case your module has it's own dependencies, you can announce them by adding sth like this into the `module` element:

```
<dependencies>
    <module name="com.example.implementation"/>
</dependencies>
```

I would advise to deploy each of the libraries in it's own module for (like the name suggests ;) modularity. You could then exchange them individually.

Comment: great answer! thank you! I particularly appreciate the warning, and will seriously think about it!

Comment: @FabioB. - glad I could make a difference :)

Comment: For development purposes, bloated WAR files can be detrimental as they reduce the number of redeploys you can make before a server reboot. You only get so much PermGen space for redeploy. Sure you can't plug-and-play into other containers, but how often does the typical developer completely change JEE containers..