# Where to put a shared library in JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jboss, shared-libraries

I have multiple web applications each using `spring-hibernate` and other open source libraries and portlets, so basically now each war file includes those jar files. How do I move these jars to a common location so that I don't have to put these in each war file? My jars are places in `D:/` directory.

I tried creating modules but no success. e.g. if I added jar

```
<resources>
    <resource-root path="mylib.jar"/>
</resources>
```

and mylib.jar needs another ABC class. That ABC class is in my WAR class-path. Here I get exception while loading this module. mylib.jar could not find ABC class and throws exception.

Comment: Using modules is definitely the way to go for commonly used libs with recent JBoss versions. Here I have explained module creation in detail, perhaps iit can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852144/jboss-7-project-libraries-as-a-module/14852880

Comment: question edited: exception explained for module

Comment: If your common lib/module needs a class that will be deployed with the application, then I'm afraid it's a lost cause. But it sounds strange that spring-hibernate should depend on your application. Perhaps you can do some untangling first, or I maybe I'm misunderstanding the issue.

Comment: How can I check class loading in JBOSS. I want to see order of class loading

Answer (score 4):

If those libraries are reused in several applications, probably the best solution would be to create JBoss modules.

For example, OJDBC library is used in several projects I'm developing. So, I added a new module to JBoss 7: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CreateAModuleForOracleDatasourceInJBoss711Final (it's just an example).

But you said, that you tried creating modules, but with no luck. What was the problem? Did you get some errors?

EDIT
Answer updated in connection with updated question.

So, if I understood correctly, we can divide your libraries into two categories:

1. First category is "standard libraries": Spring, Hibernate, Log4j etc. So, these libraries might be added as modules into JBoss AS and reused in every WAR (scope=provided in Maven's dependency).
2. Any other non-standard libraries (i.e. written by yourself) might be added as modules as well. If these libraries require some other dependencies - these dependencies must be listed in module's XML file, as described in: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Module+descriptors

Hope this helps at least a bit :)

Comment: How can I check class loading in JBOSS. I want to see order of class loading. There might be a chance that module loads first and class in classpath loads after it. So this might be a cause of error